# Basic MySQL query is pretty slow. Am I indexing my tables properly?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm currently in the process of optimizing a very large MySQL database, around which I'm building a web-based query interface.

The database will have two tables. The first table is already optimized (I believe), and contains information regarding 950 meteorological data observation stations across the US:

```
Description for: stations (950 records)
+-----------+------------+--------+-------+---------+----------------+
|Field      |Type        | NULL   |KEY    | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------+--------+-------+---------+----------------+
|id         |INT         |NO      |PRI    |NULL     |auto_increment  |
|stationID  |char(4)     |NO      |PRI    |NULL     |                |
|name       |varchar(16) |YES     |       |NULL     |                |
|state      |char(2)     |YES     |MUL    |NULL     |                |
|lat        |float(6,2)  |YES     |       |NULL     |                |
|lon        |float(6,2)  |YES     |       |NULL     |                |
|elev       |INT         |YES     |       |NULL     |                |
+-----------+------------+--------+-------+---------+----------------+
```

The other table contains observations collected at these stations from 2014 through 2017 (constructed, not optimized):

```
Description for: metar_records (359786049 records)
+-----------+------------+--------+-------+---------+----------------+
|Field      |Type        | NULL   |KEY    | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------+--------+-------+---------+----------------+
|auto_id    |INT         |NO      |PRI    |NULL     |auto_increment  |
|stationID  |char(4)     |NO      |MUL    |0        |                |
|zdatetime  |datetime    |NO      |       |NULL     |                |
|ldatetime  |datetime    |NO      |       |NULL     |                |
|temp       |tinyint(4)  |YES     |       |NULL     |                |
|dew        |tinyint(4)  |YES     |       |NULL     |                |
|wspd       |tinyint(3)  |YES     |       |NULL     | #unsigned      |
|wdir       |tinyint(3)  |YES     |       |NULL     | #unsigned      |
|wgust      |tinyint(3)  |YES     |       |NULL     | #unsigned      |
|VRB        |char(3)     |YES     |       |NULL     |                |
+-----------+------------+--------+-------+---------+----------------+
```

where stationID is the field upon which the two tables are related. The metar_records has a unique index on `('stationID', 'zdatetime')`. A list of `metar_records` table indexes:

```
+-------------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|Table        |Non_UNQ |Key_name |Seq_in_index|Column_name|Cardinality|Index_type|
+-------------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|metar_records|0       |PRIMARY  |1           |auto_id    |358374698  |BTREE     |
|metar_records|0       |sz_date  |1           |stationID  |820079     |BTREE     |
|metar_records|0       |sz_date  |2           |zdatetime  |358374698  |BTREE     |
|metar_records|1       |stationID|1           |stationID  |598288     |BTREE     |
+-------------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

---

**Here's where I'm really confused:** I also have a test table (called `metar_test`), which is identical to `metar_records` aside from having no auto_increment field, and *has no indexes whatsoever*. Execution of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM metar_test;` lasts 0.02 seconds **at most**, whereas `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM metar_records;` takes roughly 1 minute and 18 seconds to complete.

I understand that having a table this large will result in some long query times, but `metar_records` is only 3.36 times larger than `metar_test` -- why is there such a large discrepancy between the `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` queries for the two tables? I'm not particularly well versed in data storage, but this difference seems unexpectedly large to me.

How can I improve my indexing to optimize the large table size? Is it possible to reduce the query duration from here?

Comment: Indexes should not affect those queries at all; indexes help on queries filtered/joined/grouped on the fields indexed; but should generally not have an negative impact on select queries not filtering/joining/grouping on them. I'd suggest double checking the differences between the table; including charset, collation, and storage engine.

Comment: How many rows are currently in the larger table? How much will it grow? Have you considered "partitioning"? (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html)

Comment: @Used_By_Already 359786049 rows in the larger table. Not sure if it'll grow yet. I'm building this basically for an interview portfolio and I have yet to decide whether or not I'm going to maintain it to keep it up to date. Partitioning is something I'm going to have to explore a bit. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: partitioning wouldn't speed-up `select count(*)` unless the dbms also supports parallel processing. `select count(*)` is doing a table scan and so disk access speed is possibly the bottleneck (and could account for why the difference between the test table and real table).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select count(stationID) 
from metar_records
```

This will make the query optimizer to use the index of stationID and therefore reading less data as the count(*) which reads through full data.

Comment: Tried this, returned the count in 1 minute 17 seconds. Not much better :/

Answer (score 0):

I would reconstruct your tables in such way.

Stations.
Id as auto inc.
StationId char (4) unique
Rest...

Metar_records
Id  as auto inc
StationId referencing stations.id
Rest...

This way your key length are way smaller and numeric. Will boost up your performance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the "Query cache" turned on.  That makes it so that running *exactly* the same query a second time is very fast.  To properly time a query, do this twice and take the second timing:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...
```

`COUNT(*)` is the usual pattern for counting rows.  `COUNT(col)` is slower because it needs to check each `col` for being `NOT NULL`.

You have 3 `INDEXes` on your big table; you need only one:

```
PRIMARY KEY(stationID, zdatetime)
```

And, by clustering that way, several likely queries will run faster.

Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

You should use `ENGINE=InnoDB`, not `ENGINE=MyISAM` (see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`).

`SELECT COUNT(*) ...` is not a very common query; you should not take much stock in how fast it runs.

`PARTITIONing` is not likely to help performance.  Let's see more of your queries -- to double check my claim.  MySQL has no parallel processing, even for `PARTITIONed` tables.

Also toss the `id AUTO_INCREMENT` from the Stations table; instead, have `PRIMARY KEY(stationID)`.